# When do we conclude that GCD is 1 using GCD algorithm,

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

While I was studying GCD, I found out that `GCD(4883,4369)=257` while `GCD(30030, 257)=1`. I learned that if you run the GCD algorithm and the last remainder is 0, then it means GCD is 1. However, in GCD(4883,4369), the professor answers it as 257 while it has a remainder of 0!! Why?

Comment: I just want to ask in terms of GCD algorithm itself since I may ended up with large numbers

Answer (score 4):

The GCD algorithm *always* terminates with a remainder of $0$. The important number is the remainder on the penultimate step.

Comment: Thank you so much. What do you mean by  penultimate step?

Comment: Penultimate means last-but-one.